# Rotate with RotateX have glitch on FireFox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I done a `transform` effect with `rotate` and `rotateX` and it's working fine on `chrome` but working bad on `fire fox` with glitch!

```
.Stats.flipped {
transform: rotateX( 180deg ) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX( 180deg ) rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX( 180deg ) rotate(45deg);
}
```

if you see this on chrome it's working good but on fire fox it will run smoothly `rotateX 180 deg` first then run `rotate 45 deg` without any transition! and seems wrong rotation! I want it working good like chrome!

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dn7gdr92/1/)**
*(Please check this only on FireFox)*

any suggest or solution?

*FireFox version: 44.0.2 and 45.0.1 checked*

Comment: I see it perfectly on firefox 45.0.1 in MacOSX. Very smooth and correct rotation.

Comment: oh! so it's FF version issue!? my version is 44.0.2 on windows @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: No, It got issue yet with your example. I tested on my laptop, win 8, and my pc is win 10, both have same problem. @Harry

Comment: But it says: Fire fox is up to date!  in about section @Harry and i will check ff website for download new one (45.0), but wondering is there any solution for fix this on old version?

Comment: @Harry I updated to 45.0 but still have this problem! did you test it on hover effect? My problem is on hover.

Comment: @jiff: Actually now that I test again, I think I can see a difference between Chrome and FF (but not in the way you are describing). In Chrome, on hover there is top-bottom flip whereas in FF the flip is kind of diagonal-ish. Is that what you are referring to? It kind of looks like Chrome is flipping the X axis of the rotated element whereas FF is flipping the X axis of the original element. I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: @Harry 's comment makes lot of sense. However, in my Mac Book Pro (Intel i7 + 4 GB RAM) and Firefox 45.0.1 I can play that animation smoothly, so maybe depends on the machine that reproduces that transition. As an aside comment, note than `@keyframes` animations eat less memory from system than `transition` property. You can test with the performance tool in your developer tools (firefox and chrome), and you can see how many memory needs firefox and chrome with transition and with keyframes animation.

Comment: @Harry yes, I think that's it. any idea for fix this?

Comment: None that I could think of right now @jiff I tried using matrix3d but that changed nothing. If I can find any, I'll add as answer :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, if I understand you right: i didn't use keyframes, but as i said in comment, I tested on two machines and both have same issue to rendering transform.